# jq - how |= operator works?

Tags: jq

In the [JQ Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), there is an Update-assignment: **|=** filter and its example.

```
jq '(..|select(type=="boolean")) |= if . then 1 else 0 end'
Input   [true,false,[5,true,[true,[false]],false]]
Output  [1,0,[5,1,[1,[0]],0]]
```

Why this does not produce a JSON stream below but maintains the original nested list format?

```
1
0
1
1
0
0
```

For me, **(..|select(type=="boolean"))** produces:

```
true
false
true
true
false
false
```

Then applying **|= if . then 1 else 0 end** would not produce this?

```
1
0
1
1
0
0
```

Please help understand how **|= ** operation maintains can maintain the format of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the right-hand side of `|=`, the `.` doesn't refer to each Boolean value output by the left-hand side. It refers to the path *to* each value produced by the left-hand side.

The filter `(..|select(type=="boolean")) |= if . then 1 else 0 end`, given your input, is equivalent to

```
.[0] |= if . then 1 else 0 end | 
.[1] |= if . then 1 else 0 end |
.[2][0] |= if . then 1 else 0 end | ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So dot (.) can mean a json path as well as a json element, which I was not aware.

Answer (score 2):

Any assignment, whether it's via `=`, `|=` or any other, does not change the context as a result of the assignment. It just updates the selected value and passes along the original `.` input. And as chepner points out, the expression expanded out is just a sequence of assignments, none of which changes the context.

If you wanted to get just the mapped out values, you wouldn't want to do an assignment here and just do a regular pipe.

```
.. | select(type=="boolean") | if . then 1 else 0 end
```